# userName verification with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Username Availability**

I want to make an Ajax call that will read data from an input box in html, then call `taken.php`, which checks if this username is already taken.

My idea is that it will write to GET parameter like this:
`taken.php?value=something`
Does anybody know how to this with jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userName").change(function () {
        var userName = $("#userName").val().trim();

        if (userName != "") {
            $("#userNameError").show();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'checkUserName.php',
                type: 'get',
                data: {key: "userName"},

            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is what I've done so far.

Comment: You can follow this article to check username availability. [Code](http://phppot.com/jquery/live-username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery-ajax/) & [Demo](http://phppot.com/demo/live-username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: means you want it as current url?value = something ?

Comment: Note: this article is using `mysql` as a DB driver you should use `mysqli` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass `username` to `checkUserName.php` using `get` request

```
var userName = $("#userName").val().trim();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "checkUserName.php",
        data: {
            key: userName
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);

        }
    });
```

in PHP file you can get like this

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['key'];
    echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have everything but the return there.  I personally prefer `post` but what you have with a boolean return should suffice

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#userName").change(function () {
    var userName = $("#userName").val().trim();

    if (userName != "") {
        $("#userNameError").show();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'taken.php',
            type: 'get',
            data: {key: "userName"},
        }).done(function(d){
          //this is your callback.  
          //this will return the value echod by taken.php 
          //with a get of key = username
        });
      }
  });
});
```

I would prefer a post like:

```
$.post('taken.php',{
  key:$("#userName").val().trim();
},function(d){
  // this is your callback 
}
```

Comment: but what i have to do to see what taken.php responded?